# bash loop error : Get JSON Object by property with jq / bash

Tags: bash, jq

I would like to get the values from Json file. Which is working.

`JsonFileToTest`:

```
{
  "permissions": [
    {
      "emailid": "test1@test.com",
      "rights": "read"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "test2@test.com",
      "rights": "read"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
readPermissions=($(jq -r '.permissions' JsonFileToTest))

# The command below works perfectly, But when I Put it in a loop, It does not.
#echo ${readPermissions[@]} | jq 'values[].emailid'

for vals in ${readPermissions[@]}
do
   # I would like o extract the email id of the user. The loop is not working atm.  
    echo ${vals[@]} | jq 'values[].emailid'
done
```

what am I missing here?
thanks

Comment: `JsonFileToTest` isn't valid json, but it looks like valid javascript.

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29); `array=( $(...anything...) )` isn't a reliable way to populate an array in bash. And without more quotes, `for item in ${items[@]}` isn't a reliable way to iterate over an array, either.

Comment: Why not just `jq -r '.permissions[].emailid' file`?

Comment: That said, I don't know why you're using a shell loop at all instead of having a single invocation of jq do all the work. If it's a matter of iterating over results, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to do it this way, that might look like:

```
readarray -t permissions < <(jq -c '.permissions[]' JsonFileToTest)
for permissionSet in "${permissions[@]}"; do
  jq -r '.emailid' <<<"$permissionSet"
done
```

Note that we're telling jq to print one line per item (with `-c`), and using `readarray -t` to read each line into an array element (unlike the `array=( $(...command...) )` antipattern, which splits not just on newlines but on other whitespace as well, and expands globs in the process).

---

But there's no reason whatsoever to do any of that. You'll get the *exact* same result simply running:

```
jq -r '.permissions[].emailid' JsonFileToTest
```